# Keras Model using Tensorflow backend - On Predict throwing Invalid Argument Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, data-science

I had trained Keras model while using "glove.42B.300d.txt" for word-vectors. The model training went smooth, While predicting I get the error :

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[18,28] = 137077 is not in [0, 137077) [[Node: embedding_1_1/Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](embedding_1/embeddings/read, _arg_input_2_0_2)]].

Caused by op u'embedding_1_1/Gather
```

> Is this because of version conflict of tensorflow I have 1.2.1? Your
>   guidance in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks

#### Model

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(nb_words,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False)
```

> #### Model Architecture

```
sequence_1_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences_1 = embedding_layer(sequence_1_input)
x1 = Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences_1)
x1 = MaxPooling1D(10)(x1)
x1 = Flatten()(x1)
x1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x1)
x1 = Dropout(0.2)(x1)

sequence_2_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences_2 = embedding_layer(sequence_2_input)
y1 = Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences_2)
y1 = MaxPooling1D(10)(y1)
y1 = Flatten()(y1)
y1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(y1)
y1 = Dropout(0.2)(y1)

merged = merge([x1,y1], mode='concat')
merged = BatchNormalization()(merged)
merged = Dense(64, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = Dropout(0.2)(merged)
merged = BatchNormalization()(merged)
preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)
model = Model(input=[sequence_1_input,sequence_2_input], output=preds)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['acc'])
```

#### Data Shape

- test_data_1: 2345796x30
- test_data_2: 2345796x30
- train_data_1: 404290x30
- train_data_2: 404290x30

Comment: Please provide us with model definition and data set shape as it's impossible to help you without these details.

Comment: Thanks added the requirements please check.

Comment: Is `nb_words` equal to `137077`? Does either `test_data_1` or `test_data_2` contain word indices larger than or equal to `137077`?